# What is the best approach to secure JWTs?

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, jwt, authorization

Since there's not much you can do if the token gets compromised. The user has access to everything unless the token expires. I was thinking about an approach which might provide an additional layer of security, but not sure?

What if we add an IP address in the payload, and compare it on the server from the request headers?

Suppose my payload object looks like -

```
{
  user_id: 'xyz',
  email: 'john@doe.com',
  user_ip: '89.102.22.95'
}
```

On the server, we'll compare the IP saved in the payload and the IP from which the request was made.

```
if (user_ip == req.connection.remoteAddress) {
  /* It's a valid request */
} else { 
  /* Verify Identify using an email confirmation */ 
}
```

What this basically says is, even if the token has been compromised, we'll have an additional layer of security which will match the IP from which the token was generated, and the IP from which the request was made.

Is this a good solution, to make it a bit more secure?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is a good solution, because users may change between wifi / mobile networks, which also change their IP address.

A better approach I can think of is to store all IP addresses that is used by an user on a separated table. For each request, we check if the user had that IP address in their "whitelist" (looks like Steam and Parsec use this method).

Comment: What's the purpose of a jwt then? You could just use a plain session, and it would be more secure.

Comment: Yes, I also agree that plain session is more secure, even though it requires a bit more work. Either way, it's better to have a cache layer, because this approach will put more stress on database.